# Send automatic input to a script called by another script in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working on a bash script (my_script) in which I call many scripts, they all together automate a work flow.

But when I call one particular (ksh/bash) script (master_script) there are many inputs and checks taken (not arguments) in it.

It is slowing down the whole of the automation, as every time I have to super wise it and enter the values manually.

I have no option to modify or make a new script (work constraints)

**Every time the  questions are same. I am trying to take all the answers before executing master_script except one answer(whose value depends on the execution) and then feed it to the master_script at the correct time.**

***Is there a way we can pass the value to the master_script, during its execution from within my_script.? ./master_script<< EOF .. EOF will not help as I have to enter one answer myself.***

The below is just an example and my creation, but depicts what exactly is my requirement.

Example code

## my_script

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Proceeding...."
#calling master_script
/master_script $arg1 $arg2
echo "Completed.."
echo "Executing other scripts"
/other_scripts"
```

## Execution

```
$ sh ./my_script
Proceeding....

Started master_script..

Press Enter to Proceed MY_INPUT

Enter username to add (eg.user123) MY_UNAME

Enter preferred uid (eg.1234) MY_UID

Do you want to bla bla..(Y/n) MY_INPUT

Please select among the following
 1.option1
 2.Option2

Selection: MY_SELECTION

Please choose which extension to use
 1.ext1
 2.ext2
 3.ext3
 4.ext4

Do you want to bla bla 2..(Y/n) MY_INPUT

Ended master script
Completed..

Executing other scripts
```

## Requirement

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Proceeding...."
# get values for master script
read -p "Proceed(Y/n):" proceed1 
read -p "Uname:" uname
read -p "Uid:" uid
read -p "bla bla (Y/n):" bla1
read -p "Selection(1/2):" selection1
read -p "bla bla 2(Y/n):" bla2
#calling master_script
./master_script $arg1 $arg2 {all_inputs}
#Silent Execution of master_script until choosing execution...
Please choose which extension to use
 1. ext1
 2. ext2
 3. ext3
 4. ext4
#Silent Execution of master_script after choosing ext and continue with other scripts
./other_scripts
echo "Completed.."
```

> I've read about expect/send combination, but I'm unable to comprehend
>   how to use it. Any inputs will be greatly helpful

## EDIT

> I am also not sure about ./master_script<< EOF ... EOF  as I have to enter one
>   answer in the middle of execution myself.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution using *here documents* and redirecting the input:

```
./master_script "$arg1" "$arg2" << ENDINPUT
$proceed1
$uname
$uid
$bla1
$selection1
ENDINPUT
```

Remark 1: the final ENDINPUT must start the line, don't indent! See [Man bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents)

Remark 2: some scripts or programs check if the input comes from an actual terminal (calling `isatty()`), for instance when typing a password. It is still possible to automate the entries, but it is much more tricky.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention pointers won't help, there is one particular input which will be variable and can't be passed before hand.. It has to be manually entered based on the execution of the script.. I'll update the question now..

Comment: what do you mean by pointers ? which input field can't be passed ?

Comment: Please check the updated question. Thank you for the answer which showed me the blind spot in the whole question. Thanks very much :)